# $\Omega X$ when X is a not fibrant simplicial set?

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

How can I define $\Omega X$ when $X\in\mathsf{sSet}_{\ast}$ but it is not fibrant?. Actually, I would like to formulate the 'Group completion theorem' in simplicial setting, I mean

> $H_{\ast}(M)[\pi_{0}^{-1}]\cong H_{\ast}(\Omega BM)$
>   , when $\pi_{0}$ is in the center of $H_{\ast}(M)$.

But it does not make sense. Please, any suggestion?.

Comment: You can take a fibrant replacement first.

Comment: Right!, but what if I take $\Omega X=\mathbf{hom}_{\ast}(\mathrm{Ex}^{\infty} S^{1},X)$?. Is this loop functor 'well-behaved' compared with (according to your advice) $\mathbf{hom}_{\ast}(S^{1},\mathrm{Ex}^{\infty}X)$?, I mean whether they are weak equivalent. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The loop space $\Omega X$ is always a homotopy pullback of the span $* \to X \leftarrow *$.

In a model category, the homotopy pullback $D$ of a span $A \to C \leftarrow B$ can always be given by a regular pullback:

$$ \require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
D @>>> PC
\\ @VVV @VVV
\\A \times B @>>> C \times C
\end{CD} $$

where the arrow $PC \to C \times C$ is any path space fibration.

I am rusty on details, but I think in simplicial sets, $PC = C^{\Delta[1]}$ with the obvious map to $C \times C$ is such a thing.